# Handling Id's of views without switch

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

**-** The below is a switch statement which receives an integer, according to which we need to fire a method with its mapped view.

```
if (newObservation.consciousLevel.getValue() != null) {
            switch (newObservation.consciousLevel.getValue()) {
            case 0:
                // rb_alert.setChecked(true);
                // sg_conscious.check(R.id.sg_alert);
                processSegmentRadioGroupChange(sg_conscious, R.id.sg_alert);
                break;
            case 1:
                // rb_voice.setChecked(true);
                // sg_conscious.check(R.id.sg_voice);
                processSegmentRadioGroupChange(sg_conscious, R.id.sg_voice);
                break;
            case 3:
                // rb_pain.setChecked(true);
                // sg_conscious.check(R.id.sg_pain);
                processSegmentRadioGroupChange(sg_conscious, R.id.sg_pain);
                break;
            case 4:
                // rb_unresponsive.setChecked(true);
                // sg_conscious.check(R.id.sg_unresponsive);
                processSegmentRadioGroupChange(sg_conscious,
                        R.id.sg_unresponsive);
                break;
            }

        }
```

**-** Now somehow i don't want to use the switch statement instead i want to modify this code in the below manner,

```
intbuttonIndex = observation.consciousLevel.getValue();
setButton(sg_conscious, buttonIndex);
```

Can you please help me achieve this............ Can i achieve this using Reflection Class ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a HashMap that provides mappings of 0,1,2,3,4,etc to the id you wish them to map to.  Then just call  `processSegmentRadioGroupChange(sg_conscious, myMap.get(newObservation.consciousLevel.getValue()));`

Comment: A `SparseArray` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**-** I think **enum** will be a **better approach** to what you are trying to accomplish here.

**-** In the present circumstances, what you are receiving in the switch is an integer with value 0,1,2,3 and 4, and you are trying to map it with certain ids of the views, so switch here is apt.

**-** Now about reflection, its has great APIs set, but i won't recommend someone using it until they really know when to use it and when to not........

**Here are few links which shows why Reflection is great but should be avoided:**

http://java.dzone.com/news/avoid-reflection

http://advint.extrapro.ru/articles/reflection.php